# Error:(44, 13) Failed to resolve: org.achartengine:achartengine:1.2.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When I use `android studio 3.0` and `gradle ver 3.5` I'm geting this error:

```
Error:(44, 13) Failed to resolve: org.achartengine:achartengine:1.2.0
```

But I have already added these dependencies in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'org.achartengine:achartengine:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.9.1'
    compile 'nl.qbusict:cupboard:2.1.1'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me, whats wrong with `gradle 3.5` , when I switch to `gradle 2.14.1` it's working fine.